# Can a coroutine scope leak an activity/fragment?

Tags: android, memory-leaks, kotlin-coroutines

I need to save a `EditText` data into a file when to user exits the activity. I know I have plenty of options depending on how important saving that data for me. But for this particular case I'm ok that I can afford losing it so best-afford is fine.

We could maybe create a background service to decouple it entirely from the host activity. However,I was also thinking of creating a coroutine scope that might outlive the activity (i.e.: a singleton NonUIScope) and call the block like;

```
override fun onSaveInstanceState(bundle: ...) {
    ...
    mInput = et.text.toString()
}

override fun onDestroy() {
    NonUIScope.launch {
         Downloader.saveData(mInput)
    }
}
```

There might be slightly different implementations to achieve the same goal of course, for instance, using `onSavedInstanceSate()` instead of writing it into a file but my point is: if I use the `ApplicationScope` that I've created, could I potentially leak the activity (even there's no UI reference in the coroutine)?

Comment: Is `saveData()` an instance method of your Activity? If so, I believe the activity will stay in memory as long as the method is still running (you could test this using the memory profiler in Android Studio). Besides the potential leak, the user might kill the app before the data is saved. A better approach would be to use WorkManager, it is convenient for these situations, and setting it up is easy.

Comment: Good point. But lets assume lambda does not close on any activity related things. Secondly, ‘WorkManager’ is not really well designed for immediate actions as far as I know.

Comment: Even if `saveData()` doesn't use anything from the Activity, the fact that it's an instance method means that there needs to be an instance of the Activity running in order for the method to run. If however, `saveData()` was static, I think it wouldn't stop the Activity from being garbage collected. Regarding workManager not being well designed for immediate actions, I'd be curious to see where you read this, I've used it in production apps for both immediate and periodic work, and it worked just fine.

Comment: I tried to make it more clear that the `saveData` really has nothing to do with the `Activity` (see the code). About `WorkManager` being not very-well suited about "immediate actions": please take a look at https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager

Answer (score 1):

As long as `NonUIScope` is not related in any way to your activity and also Downloader class doesn't hold an instance of your activity, it will not leak your activity.

E.g. if you use `GlobalScope`, the life time of the launched coroutine is limited only by the lifetime of the whole application, not by your activity.